# Retrofit 2 dependency

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, retrofit

I tried to add Retrofit2 in my project. I did such actions:

- Added to my *build.gradle* dependency *compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'* - it wasn't successfull (Gradle build failed: file cannot be resolved)
- Updtaed Android SDK tools  - it didn't help
- Put into project configuration versions of Android and Gradle plugins: Android - 2.3.3, Gradle - 3.3. Same result: file cannot be resolved.

All these actions were not successfull. I updated Gradle (AS offered it for me, and I accepted), but it also wasn't helpful. And now, after all actions, my project takes a lot of time to build (in online-work mode it takes 1 hour). Offline mode - 2-3 minutes.
Does anybody know, what happened? 
**Updated: my gradle files**
**Module**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    compileOptions.encoding = "windows-1251"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ua.grant.smart"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.5"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-fragment:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
}
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
}
```

**App (top level)**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
jcenter()
}
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` files (root project directory and module directory)?

Comment: why you declare 2 `dependencies` in one gradle? i though that's the problem

Comment: ok, I'll try to put all of them into one block. Should I do this in outer block, or in block inside android?

Comment: It's a great problem to build project now in online mode - I started synchronization, and I think that it will finish during one hour. I don't know, why it appears - it started after I updated AS.

Answer (score 3):

Modify from

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    compileOptions.encoding = "windows-1251"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ua.grant.smart"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.5"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}   
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-fragment:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
 }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
}
```

To

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    compileOptions.encoding = "windows-1251"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ua.grant.smart"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.5"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}   
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-fragment:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
}
```

Comment: I tried this. It does not work for me. Same result: failed to resolve. And project was built during 1 hour.

Comment: @user3533397 try to invalidate cache. `File -> Invalidate Cache / Restart ->Invalidate and Restart`. Also i updated my answer. Do new changes from gradle then invalidate cache.

Comment: I'll try this. But why my project is building 1 hour?

Comment: I tried to uninstall AS and installed the latest version. But it didn't help.

Comment: Why did you add `compileOptions.encoding = "windows-1251"`?

Comment: I don't remember - maybe, it was there from the start of project. Can it be a reason of slow building?

Comment: Don't think so.